# How to get total CPU time for android app

Tags: java, android, adb, battery

[Ideal cpu percent for android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26502872/ideal-cpu-percent-for-android-app)

I used to see the break down of battery usage about 5 weeks ago similar to the above topic's answer with `CPU total`, `CPU foreground`, `GPS` (because my app use GPS), and `Computed power usage`. However, after an auto update, the `Battery Usage` now shows only `While in active use` and `While in background` which is pretty much useless information and it does not even track the time my app use in the background properly (always 0 minutes even after running in the background for 16 hours - I checked the log to verify this).

Ideally, I would like either see the detailed breakdown again so I know exactly how much total time was requested for each category. Should I flash an earlier version of android or just install the right Settings apk file? If so, could you please tell me your Settings's version?

Not ideally, I can get the cpu usage break down through `adb shell /system/bin/dumpsys cpuinfo`, however I cannot control the time I want to sample like using the previous setting app (full charging & unplug would start the timer). Anyone have experience using adb to specify which time range I would like to query CPU time from?